# Rotate timeseries values around an angle with Python

Tags: python, pandas, math, matrix, vector

I have a timeseries which for the sake of simplicity looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

points = [0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame(points)
df.plot(legend=False)
```

[image]

Now I want to rotate the values based on a specific angle, which will be between 0 and 90 degrees.

Note: I don't really need to be able to plot the values but I'm interested in the resulting values.

The resulting plot for a rotation of 90 degrees would look, according to matplotlib, like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot, transforms

base = pyplot.gca().transData
rot  = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(90)
pyplot.plot(df, transform=rot+base)
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

So I'm asking, what is the mathematical/programmatic way to get values rotated by an angle?

Comment: I suppose it would better not rotate the plot, but exchange X- and Y- data (or reassign axes if possible)

Comment: Wouldn't exchanging X- and Y-data just work for a 90 degree rotation? I need it for every angle, beeing more specific for a rotation of degree r which is between 0 > r > 90

Comment: Yes, it works only for 90 degrees.  Do you need a formula to rotate point by any angle? If yes, what are source coordinates - calculated by pyplot or just data point (y=1; x=2.3...) ?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need the formula to rotate a point by any angle please. I'm sorry if this wasn't obvious formulated in my question. The coordinates are e.g. (x=datetime, y=2.3), but the datetime can be converted to an continous integer series so [(x=0, y=2.3), (x=1, y=1.0), (x=2, y=2.2), ..]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

Rotate a point in XYZ space around the Z axis by γ angle：

```
import numpy as np
import math

def rotate_z(x, y, z, gamma):
    gamma = gamma * (np.pi / 180)
    x_r = np.cos(gamma)*x - np.sin(gamma)*y
    y_r = np.sin(gamma)*x + np.cos(gamma)*y
    z_r = z
    print(f"{(x, y, z)} rotate {gamma*(180/np.pi)} degrees around the Z-axis,result {(x_r, y_r, z_r)}")
    return x_r, y_r, z_r
```

The formula is below:
[rotate some degrees around the z-axis to get result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZzXO.png)

Comment: Small addition: to rotate about arbitrary point cx, cy rather than 0,0, formula will be: `x_r = cx + np.cos(gamma)*(x-cx) - np.sin(gamma)*(y-cy)` and similar for y_r

Comment: x = x2 + (x1 - x2)cosγ - (y1 - y2)sinγ
y = y2 + (y1 - y2)cosγ + (x1 - x2)sinγ
Yes, that is right~